# Drawing AND/OR trees in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

Is there a simple way to achieve this type of graph?

[image]

Obviously a lot neater than this...
But the important feature is the join between the two children of P.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution uses the powerful `forest` package together with the `angles` library of PGF/TikZ.

A special style, `tree angle` is defined which marks the angle between a child node and the next sibling.

The combination allows the tree itself to be specified very concisely:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, angles}
\begin{document}
\forestset{
  tree angle/.style={
    tikz={\path () coordinate (A) -- (!u) coordinate (B) -- (!n) coordinate (C) pic [draw] {angle};}
  }
}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    draw,
    circle,
    edge={-{Stealth[]}},
    l sep+=7.5pt
  },
  [P
  [Q, tree angle
      [T, tree angle]
      [U]
    ]
    [R]
    [S
      [V]
      [W, tree angle]
      [X]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: tree angles in a forest]

Comment: Can you explain the  tree angle rule? It doesn't render well for rectangle boxes.

Answer (score 6):

You should study pgfmanual (v2.10 as of mine) for `trees` library (sections 18.Making Trees Grow, 53.Tree Library) and placing nodes on a line or curve (sections 16.8 and 16.9).

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.5cm, grow=down,
    every node/.style={draw, circle, thin},
    edge from parent/.style={-latex, thick, draw}
]
\node (P) {P}
    child {node (Q) {Q}
        child {node (T) {T}}
        child {node (U) {U}}
    }
    child {node (R) {R}}
    child {node (S) {S}};

\path (P) -- coordinate[midway] (PQ) (Q);
\path (P) -- coordinate[midway] (PR) (R);

\draw (PQ) to[bend right=22] (PR);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Code output]