# Draw and-or trees' arc with tikz tree library

Tags: tikz-trees, trees

I'm trying to get a similar result of this question: [Drawing AND/OR trees in Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16210/drawing-and-or-trees-in-tikz).

However, I'm trying the `trees` library from tikz and was trying to get the automatic arc that is produced with the access to the siblings and parents of the `forest` package shown in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251865/7561). However, I can't find a way to access the first and last child of a node.

Basically, I want to add to my `and` style a way to automatically produce an arc between all its children (like in the previous question). I know that I can manually name the nodes and create the arc (e.g., `\path (P) -- coordinate[midway] (PQ) (Q);`), but I will like an automatic solution.

```
% !TeX program=lualatex
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
graphdrawing,
graphs,
}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  and/.style={fill=red!50, draw=red, graphs/source edge style=red},
  or/.style={fill=cyan!50, draw=black, graphs/source edge clear}
]
\graph[
  tree layout, fresh nodes, 
  sibling distance=1.5cm, layer distance=1cm, 
  nodes={shape=circle, draw, minimum width=.5cm}, 
  edge quotes={fill=white, inner sep=1pt}, 
  grow=down,
  level/.append code={\ifodd#1\relax\tikzset{nodes={or}}\else\tikzset{nodes={and}}\fi},
] {
  G -- {
    "" -- {
      B -- "" -- D -- "" -- S;
      P -- "" -- S
    };
    "" -- {
      B -- "" -- D -- "" -- S;
      P -- "" -- S
    }
  };
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For example, for the red nodes in the second level I want an arc. But the rest of the red nodes don't have more than one child, so they shouldn't get an arc.
[image]

Comment: I'm trying to hang a picture and to do that, I need to bang a nail into the wall to hook it onto. I know that I could do this with a hammer, I've seen the results of using a hammer and those are precisely the results I want. However, I'd like to do it with a screwdriver. How can I achieve an equally good result equally easily using a screwdriver?

Comment: Yes, because if this screwdriver also advertise that works as a hammer, I will like to know how to use it as such. Didn't know it was a bad idea to learn to use other stuff to do the same thing. Then, you can compare experiences and know for yourself.

Comment: Forest is much more powerful than the other trees stuff in TikZ, especially where automation is concerned. You can do the arcs with TikZ, but to automate it you'll need to programme a suitable algorithm etc. Obviously, if you want to do that as a learning exercise, good for you. But if you're asking here, you're asking for an existing solution. And Forest is really the best existing solution for what you want to do. Because Forest constructs the tree in `stages` it goes through multiple cycles. So code in one cycle can depend on information from a previous one e.g. the number of children.

Comment: And Forest provides `relative node names` from `nodewalk`s which you can use to specify nodes relative to others. Again, this depends on multiple cycles: you can use a reference to a node's first and last child since those nodes can be specified later in the code but exist before the references must be resolved. Of course, you can do this in TikZ, too, because you can rewrite Forest which is, after all, TikZ-based. But TikZ does ***not*** advertise itself as a ready-made solution enabling you to reference nodes which you have not yet specified in the code. There are no cycles out-of-the-box.

Comment: Maybe you can do it with the Lua stuff since you seem to be using that. Presumably the automatic layout code must do multiple cycles. Presumably it is possible to access these cycles either via an existing interface or directly by examining the code. That is, maybe there's stuff in the graph drawing part which enables something like the relative node names and cyclical resolution or, if not, you can presumably write code to do this by examining the source. But I haven't seen any examples of the kind of automation Forest does using the Lua stuff, which I'm not personally very familiar with.